# Configuring FreeRADIUS to log user commands

Tags: debian, freeradius

I need to be able to configure a radius server to log users' activities like the commands they're running whilst they were logged into a client device.  Entries should be made in the /var/log/freeradius/radius.log file.

Comment: too less information. What did you already tried, what's the exact issue you are facing. Currently you are telling your car is broken just as an opposite example

Comment: Right now it is configured to just send  the log in  info  to the file  /var/log/freeradius/radius.log  . That is is shows in the log  the user who logged in and the password they use to log in.  I want to be able to see what they did when they log in Ex ; user do ls -l  command , i can see that in the log file on the radius server .

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with Radius, it's not really what it is designed for.

What you are probably looking for is something like [tlog](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/terminal-logging) and if you want the logs all to be centrally stored setting up systemd (or what ever logger you are using) to send the logs to a central remote host (could be the same machine you are running the Radius server on).

Answer (score 0):

This functionality was never defined in a standard and so varies from vendor to vendor.  If this functionality is supported by the NAS (Network Access Server), then the NAS will copy the command entered by the user into a VSA (Vendor Specific Attribute).  The NAS will then send that attribute to the RADIUS server in an `Accounting-Request/Interim-Update` along with attributes to identify the NAS and user.  You will likely need to enable command logging via RADIUS explicitly in the NAS' configuration as it is almost never enabled by default.

For logging commands it's best to use the `linelog` module.  You'll also need a conditional check to only call linelog if the command attribute is present in the `Accounting-Request/Interim-Update` packet, as these command logging packets will be mixed in with the normal accounting stream.

I've used `HP-Command-String` as the example attribute here, but the actual attribute will vary from vendor to vendor.  You should examine the incoming `Accounting-Request` packets to see which VSA contains the command the user issued.

Add the following lines to your FreeRADIUS configuration files, and ensure `mods-available/linelog` is linked to `mods-enabled/linelog`.

**sites-available/default**

```
accounting {
    if (&HP-Command-String) {
        log_commands
    }
}
```

**mods-available/linelog**

```
linelog log_commands {
    format = "user=%{User-Name}, command=%{HP-Command-String}"
    filename = ${logdir}/radius.log
}
```

After you restart freeradius you should see commands being appended to `/var/log/radius/radius.log` or `/var/log/freeradius/radius.log` depending on your distribution.

See [mods-available/linelog](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/mods-available/linelog) for more confirmation options for the linelog module.